# copy and rename multiple .csv files from one machine to another machine using batch file

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

Data available at source

```
20161020162432intsol_wla_00000304.csv
$20161020162432intsol_wla_00000305.csv
```

& 20-30 similar files.

Data to be received at destination should be as below:

```
intsol_wla_20161020162432_00000304.csv
intsol_wla_$20161020162432_00000305.csv
```

Below is what I am trying to do:

```
copy "d:\source\\ *int.csv" "d:\destination\\ *intsol_wla_%date:~-4,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~-10,2%.csv"
```

but this returns:

```
20161020162432_intsol_wla_2016 111.csv
$20161020162432_intsol_wla_2016 111.csv
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "copy and rename ..... from one folder to another folder", and not "machines".

If that's the case, here is some code that might do the job:
(Files with $ sign make some trouble, so I created two 'for' loops to handle both cases)

```
@echo off

SET source="d:\source\"
SET dest="d:\destination\"

for %%a in (%source%$??????????????intsol_wla_*.csv) do (
    for %%F in (%%a) do (SET file=%%~nxF
        copy %%a %dest%intsol_wla_%file:~0,15%_%file:~26,8%.csv
    )
)

for %%b in (%source%??????????????intsol_wla_*.csv) do (
    for %%F in (%%b) do (SET file2=%%~nxF
        copy %%b %dest%intsol_wla_%file2:~0,14%_%file2:~25,8%.csv
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My first for lists the files, the second one takes the names and splits them at the letter i and the underscore giving four tokens.

```
NAME   20161020162432intsol_wla_00000304.csv
      $20161020162432intsol_wla_00000305.csv
TOKEN ------1--------|--2--|-3-|------4-----
```

Since the part `intsol_wla_`is constant, we need only token1 and 4

```
@Echo off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set Src=Q:\Test\2016-11\11
Set Dst=Q:\Test\Dst
PushD "%Src%"||(Echo can't cd to %Src%&Pause&Exit /b 1)
For %%A in (*intsol_wla_*.csv
  ) Do For /F "tokens=1,4 delims=i_" %%B in ("%%A"
  ) Do Echo copy "%%~fA" "%Dst%\intsol_wla_%%B_%%C"
PopD
```

OutPut, to really copy remove the echo in front of copy.

```
copy "Q:\Test\2016-11\11\$20161020162432intsol_wla_00000305.csv" "Q:\Test\Dst\intsol_wla_$20161020162432_00000305.csv"
copy "Q:\Test\2016-11\11\20161020162432intsol_wla_00000304.csv" "Q:\Test\Dst\intsol_wla_20161020162432_00000304.csv"
```

Comment: didn't worked, destination folder is empty.

Comment: Did you remove the echo?

Comment: yes i removed the echo, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Since the test data provided by you did work here, there must be something different. Did you have an output with the echo?

Comment: no i didn't have an output with the Echo

Comment: If Src and Dst vars are valid, the Pattern `*intsol_wla_*.csv` has matches in Src I'm clueless. Something must be different and you are the only one to solve that.

Comment: sure understood, let me dig deep here and will get back to you on same

Comment: it worked. what if i need the output only as intsol_wla_20161020. instead of   intsol_wla_20161020162432_00000305.csv. kindly guide

Comment: So it worked, your question was `How do I solve this` looks like **I** solved it. But I don't see a vote up nor a check mark answered. And now you change the question in a comment. Who do expect will spoon feed you once more?

Comment: @LotPings..I am new to this forum and was not aware of the votes and check mark, but your response to the question makes it quite clear that this is what you are begging for.